# Determine if a string is inside a string

Tags: excel, vba

Looking for the best way to determine if a keyword exists inside a cell/string.

My code is searching a column.  On each loop, I want to determine if that cell is containing a certain phrase.

```
For x = 1 to 1000
If range("a" & x) contains " CERTAIN PHRASE " then b = b + 1
Next x
```

Not sure how to pick out that phrase out of a longer sentence that exists in the cell.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
    For x = 1 To 1000
        Set c = Range("A" & x).Find("certain phrase", LookIn:=xlValues)
        If Not c Is Nothing Then b = b + 1
    Next
```